# Как сделать ссылки как в ВК на пользователей без get запросов и лишних папок в сайте

Tags: php, .htaccess

Мне нужно правильно настроить .htaccess
Объясняю. Есть главный файл index.php - через него происходят редиректы на другие странички в зависимости от REQUEST_URI. Допустим пользователь пишет в адресной строке site/id123 - естевственно такой папки нет в корне сайта, но мне нужно что бы не выскакивало никаких ошибок, а пользователь так и остался в корне сайта (Index.php) - откуда я уже в зависимости от запроса его направлю на нужную страницу

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```